# Kubernetes HPA node delete grace period

Tags: kubernetes

I am using Kubernetes HPA to scale up my cluster. I have set up target CPU utilization is 50% . It is scaling up properly. But, when load decreases and it scales down so fast. I want to set a cooling period. As an example, even the CPU util is below 50% , it should wait for 60 sec before terminating a node.

I have checked this article, but it is not saying that I can change the default value in HPA, https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/index.html#termination-of-pods

Kops version :- 1.9.1

Comment: Are you using HPA to scale nodes or pods?

Answer (score 1):

This is configured at the HPA level: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#support-for-cooldown-delay

> --horizontal-pod-autoscaler-downscale-delay: The value for this option is a duration that specifies how long the autoscaler has to wait before another downscale operation can be performed after the current one has completed. The default value is 5 minutes (5m0s).

Comment: I am not certain that this is the right answer.  If I understand correctly how things work, the HPA's --horizontal-pod-autoscaler-downscale-delay configuration will instruct HPA to wait for the new duration instead of the default 5m before it starts deleting containers.

From reading the link that the OP posted, I guess that he was asking how to configure HPA to change the "kubectl delete --grace-period=<seconds>" delay from the default 30 to 60 seconds.

Comment: The grace period you are referring to is how long pods have to shut down. It’s not related to how long HPA waits to scale down.